# Using $where on value nested in object

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I am trying to run the below code:

```
    Ticket.find({
    $where: function() { return this.price <= this.refunds.minimumPrice}
    })
```

but mongo won't recognise this.refunds.minimumPrice.

How do I access values that are nested in objects in my Schema using $where?

Comment: Can you please provide the error/output you receive from this piece of code? Is this a null, undefined or something?

Comment: it returns data but the data it returns makes no sense. I think it is returning data where this.price exists. If I use shorter code `$where: this.price <= this.refunds.minimumPrice` I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'minimumPrice' of undefined` but this.refunds definitely exists